# Moving Sharepoint 2010 List Item from one folder to another folder

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2010

So Im trying to move a list item from one folder to another folder. And I tried using this code which I found(link of the source of code is below.). I keep getting a "Value does not fall within the expected range." error and I dont know why Im getting it. Can someone explain this problem to me. Thanks!

```
var listTitle = "Requests"; //list title
var itemId = 1;  //list item id
var targetFolderUrl = "/Lists/Requests/Archive";  //target folder server relative url

var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var item = list.getItemById(itemId);
ctx.load(item,['FileRef','FileDirRef']);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
   function(){
       var fileUrl = item.get_item('FileRef');
       var file = ctx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileUrl);
       var targetfileUrl = fileUrl.replace(item.get_item('FileDirRef'),targetFolderUrl); 
       file.moveTo(targetfileUrl, SP.MoveOperations.overwrite);
       ctx.executeQueryAsync(
          function(){
             console.log('List item has been moved');   
          },
          logError
       )
   },
   logError);


function logError(sender,args){
      console.log(args.get_message()); 
}
```

this is my actual code.

```
var targetFolderUrl = "/Lists/" + COMM.PROPERTY.SUSAR.LIST + "/ProductID_64";  //target folder server relative url

            var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(COMM.PROPERTY.SUSAR.LIST);
            var item = list.getItemById(66);
            ctx.load(item, ['FileRef', 'FileDirRef']);
            ctx.executeQueryAsync(
               function () {
                var fileUrl = item.get_item('FileRef');
                var file = ctx.get_web().getFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileUrl);
                var targetfileUrl = fileUrl.replace(item.get_item('FileDirRef'), targetFolderUrl);
                file.moveTo(targetfileUrl, SP.MoveOperations.overwrite);
                ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                   function () {
                    console.log('List item has been moved');
                   },
                   logError
                )
               },
               logError);


            function logError(sender, args) {
                console.log(args.get_message());
            }
```

[How to move list item into folder in Sharepoint online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36255335/how-to-move-list-item-into-folder-in-sharepoint-online)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do this without code you can use a 2010 workflow. if current item equals X, copy item in Current Item to NewList then Delete item in Current item. Just be sure to choose 2010 workflow not 2013. Also you may need to set up when new item is created or changed as the trigger. I have a receiving list that looks at a parameter and based on the parameter sends it to one of many potential lists; so I have it set up as created or changed.